# Emit actions before `toArray` - Redux Observable

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, redux-observable, rxjs6, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I'm using Redux Observable and need to solve a timing issue when firing off actions from epics.

I have an array of items that I want to loop over for making AJAX calls on each one. Immediately after receiving the AJAX response, I want to fire off some actions. After all of the AJAX responses come back for each item in the original array, I want to fire off more actions.

How can I get these actions to fire immediately after the `timer` expires even though the original array hasn't finished looping?

```js
const someEpic = action$ => (
    action$
    .pipe(
        ofType(SOME_ACTION),
        switchMap(({ payload }) => (
            from(payload) // This is an array of items
            .pipe(
                mergeMap(() => (
                    timer(5000) // This is my AJAX call
                    .pipe(
                        map(loadedAction),
                    )
                )),
                toArray(),
                map(anotherAction),
            )
        ))
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is actually emitting actions using `tap` wherever you want. This is assuming you have access to the store. For example:

```
tap(result => this.store.dispatch(...))
```

However a more "Rx" way would be splitting the chain using `multicast` and then reemitting one part immediatelly (that's the loading progress) and the other half chaining with `toArray()` to collect all results that would be then turn into another action signaling that loading is done.

```
import { range, Subject, of } from 'rxjs';
import { multicast, delay, merge, concatMap, map, toArray } from 'rxjs/operators';

const process = v => of(v).pipe(
  delay(1000),
  map(p => `processed: ${p}`),
);

range(1, 5)
  .pipe(
    concatMap(v => process(v)),
    multicast(
      () => new Subject(), 
      s => s.pipe(
        merge(s.pipe(toArray()))
      )
    ),
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs6-demo-k9hwtu?file=index.ts

Comment: I think multicast is a good concept here, but how would you do this with redux-observable? The latest version sends in `state$` instead of `store` so you can't arbitrarily dispatch.

Answer (score 0):

This requires 2 epics.

```js
const ajaxCallerEpic = action$ => (
    action$
    .pipe(
        ofType(AJAX_ACTION),
        switchMap(({
            payload,
            payloadId,
        }) => (
            merge(
                from(payload) // This is an array of items
                .pipe(
                    mergeMap(() => (
                        timer(5000) // This is my AJAX call
                        .pipe(
                            switchMap(() => (
                                merge(
                                    of(loadedAction),
                                    of(
                                        sentData(
                                            payloadId
                                        )
                                    ),
                                )
                            )),
                        )
                    )),
                ),
            )
        ))
    )
)

const ajaxResponsesEpic = action$ => (
    action$
    .pipe(
        ofType(AJAX_ACTION),
        switchMap(({
            payload,
            payloadId,
        }) => (
            action$
            .pipe(
                ofType(SENT_DATA_ACTION),
                filter(({ id }) => (
                    id === payloadId
                )),
                bufferCount(
                    payload
                    .length
                ),
                map(anotherAction),
            )
        ))
    )
)
```

The important piece is the second `SENT_DATA_ACTION`. I passed a unique id when it's called to ensure you're listening to the right one. If you don't send all of them, this will be listening for as long as the browser's open. You could always add a timeout on the inner listener to make sure it completes. The other problem would be if `ajaxResponsesEpic` sets up the `action$` listener later than when `ajaxCallerEpic` runs the AJAX calls.

It could very well end up being a `race` condition. To account for those issues, you'll want to execute `ajaxResponsesEpic` first so it sets up the action listener, and at the same time, starts the AJAX calls after it's listening.

Like so:

```js
const ajaxCallerEpic = action$ => (
    action$
    .pipe(
        ofType(AJAX_READY_ACTION),
        switchMap(({
            payload,
            payloadId,
        }) => (
            merge(
                from(payload) // This is an array of items
                .pipe(
                    mergeMap(() => (
                        timer(5000) // This is my AJAX call
                        .pipe(
                            switchMap(() => (
                                merge(
                                    of(loadedAction),
                                    of(
                                        sentAjaxData(
                                            payloadId
                                        )
                                    ),
                                )
                            )),
                        )
                    )),
                ),
            )
        ))
    )
)

const ajaxResponsesEpic = action$ => (
    action$
    .pipe(
        ofType(AJAX_ACTION),
        switchMap(({
            payload,
            payloadId,
        }) => (
            merge(
                (
                    action$
                    .pipe(
                        ofType(SENT_AJAX_DATA_ACTION),
                        filter(({ id }) => (
                            id === payloadId
                        )),
                        bufferCount(
                            payload
                            .length
                        ),
                        map(anotherAction),
                    )
                ),
                (
                    of(ajaxReadyAction)
                ),
            )
        ))
    )
)
```